# Pick first element of groupby object's group by index without converting to list

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below, I am iterating groups of `groupby` object and printing the first item in column
`b` of each group.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'b': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
groups = df.groupby('b')

for name, group in groups:
    first_item_in_b = group['b'].tolist()[0]
    print(first_item_in_b)
```

Because the `groupby` has hierarchical index, in order to pick the first element in `b` I need to
convert `b` to list first.

How can I avoid such overhead?

I cannot just remove `tolist()` like so:

```
first_item_in_b = group['b'][0]
```

because it will give `KeyError`.

Comment: `first_b` should've been `first_item_in_b`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'b': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
groups = df.groupby('b')

for name, group in groups:
    first_item_in_b = group['b'].iloc[0]
    print(first_item_in_b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
10
20
30
```

**EDIT**:

Or Using the [Fast integer location scalar accessor.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for get position of column `b`, so possible use `iat` or `iloc` only or by first value of index with column name by [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html).

Or is possible select by position by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) after selecting by column label `b`:

```
for name, group in groups:
    #first value by positions from columns names
    first_item_in_b = group.iat[0, group.columns.get_loc('b')]
    #first value by labels from index
    first_item_in_b = group.at[group.index[0],'b']

    #fast select first value
    first_item_in_b = group['b'].iat[0]
    #alternative
    first_item_in_b = group['b'].iloc[0]
    print(first_item_in_b)

10
20
30
```